# Get an integer result from a stored procedure fails using Entity Framework when calling Context.Database.SqlQuery<int>

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am trying to call a stored procedure from Entity Framework in the following way:

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqlSP, params).FirstOrDefault();
```

but I get this error:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types

With LinqPad you can see that the stored procedure is working

[image]

The generated code from LinqPad for the same call in SQL is the following

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @RETURN_VALUE Int
DECLARE @contenttype VarChar(50) = ''
DECLARE @image VarBinary(1000) = null
DECLARE @applicationid Int = 81725
DECLARE @statusid Int = 10
DECLARE @notes VarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @requestuserid Int = 59
DECLARE @assigneduserid Int = 655
DECLARE @parentid Int = 0
DECLARE @eventid Int = 0
DECLARE @discipline Int = 5
DECLARE @replyby DateTime = '2017-09-14 16:22:40.082'
DECLARE @workitemid Int = 81725
DECLARE @messagetype Int = 2
DECLARE @inspectionid Int = 6081
DECLARE @floor SmallInt = 3
-- EndRegion
exec @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[usp_InsertInspectionEventPublic] @contenttype, @image, @applicationid, @statusid, @notes, @requestuserid, @assigneduserid, @parentid, @eventid, @discipline, @replyby, @workitemid, @messagetype, @inspectionid, @floor
```

The stored procedure always returns an id in the following way:

```
select @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() from TEMPTABLE
Return @id
```

I tried this too:

```
var returnCode = new SqlParameter("@ReturnCode", SqlDbType.Int);
returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

var sql = "exec @ReturnCode =dbo.usp_insertinspectioneventpublic @contenttype, @image, @applicationid, @statusid, @notes, @requestuserid, @assigneduserid, @parentid, @eventid, @discipline, @replyby, @workitemid, @messagetype, @inspectionid, @floor";
var data = Context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql, returnCode, inParameters);
var res = data.FirstOrDefault();
return res;
```

But I am getting another error with that approach: **When executing a command, paramerters must be exclusively database parameters or values.**
Which can be the problem here?

Comment: Return value is different than a result set. The SqlQuery is returning the result set. I'm not that familiar, but you may be able to access the parameter with direction `ReturnValue` from `params` (which is a keyword so don't use it)

Answer (score 1):

`SqlQuery<T>()` is looking for a resultset, not an output parameter.

Either map an output parameter and run the batch with ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,params), or write the sqlSP batch like this:

```
declare @RETURN_VALUE INT;
exec @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[usp_InsertInspectionEventPublic] @contenttype, @image, @applicationid, @statusid, @notes, @requestuserid, @assigneduserid, @parentid, @eventid, @discipline, @replyby, @workitemid, @messagetype, @inspectionid, @floor;
SELECT @RETURN_VALUE RETURN_VALUE;
```

So that the return value comes back in a resultset.

Comment: Actually the store procedure doesn't have an output parameter declared, so I can't use something like this [dbo].[usp_InsertInspectionEventPublic] OUT myOutputParameter... The linkpad is generating the sql in that way when it calls the stored procedure. Inside the stored procedure there is a line that make the same thing that you suggest Return id after assigning the value to id. Sorry for not including the "at" on the variables in the comment, seems that this input are doesn't allow it

Comment: It's not a stored procedure output parameter, it's a return value.  That's why it's `exec @RETURN_VALUE = procname ...` instead of `exec procname @RETURN_VALUE. . .`  `return @id` outputs the data as a return value `select @id id` returns it as a resultset, like SqlQuery<T> expects.

Comment: I am confuse, do you mean 

select id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() from  TEMPTABLE 
Return id

returns a resultset?

Comment: Yes stand-alone SELECT in a stored procedure sends a resultset to the client.  You don't need a temp table .  Just `select scope_identity() id` will return a single-row, single-column resultset.

Comment: Can we continue the discussion here? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154544/room-for-heinrich-and-david-browne-microsoft